# NFC payment ring

Tags: android, nfc, payment-gateway, payment, mifare

I am working on a NFC payment Ring similar to the Mclear and the Kerv Ring but mine has a Mifare plus s2 chip. My question is how can I get a Mastercard approved chip? Or what are the steps in getting my chip approved?

Regards,

Comment: I'm sorry but your question does not look like a programming/technical question - I could answer but that would be like advertising the company I work for.
Probably you already know that the EMV (Mastercard, Visa, etc) payment system does not use Mifare. EMV-capable chips I know are either native or have a JavaCard operating system.

Comment: What chip will best suite this concept?

Comment: All vendors (Infineon, NXP, ST Microelectronics, Gemalto, G&D... and many more) have EMV-certified products (chip, operating system, applications) so Mastercard-approved too.
What do you want to achieve specifically?

Comment: What I want achieve specifically is to have my NFC to work as a payment wearable ring similar to the Ker Ring and Mclear Ring.